# custom tags for contact form 7 in mailing

Tags: php, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have created an auto-reply email for visitors who submitted a contact form and I included some custom tags like [_post_title] [_date] and [your-name]. I want to include one more tag but it is not in [Special mail tags](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/) since the tag that I want to include is a personal tag. So it can recall the category of publication into the reply email.

I've tried below code but it does not work. My personal tag is [publication-category] but not sure how to generate it to below code.

```
// Hook for additional special mail tag
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'wti_special_mail_tag', 20, 3 );

/** 
 * Special mail tag for site url
 * 
 * @param string
 * @param string
 * @param string
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function wti_special_mail_tag( $output, $name, $html )
{
   // For backwards compatibility
   $name = preg_replace( '/^wpcf7\./', '_', $name );

   if ( '_site_url' == $name ) {
      // Get the site url
      $blog_url = get_option( 'siteurl' );

                // Create clickable link
                $output = make_clickable( $blog_url );
   }

   return $output;
```

I will be grateful if someone could help me on this. Thank you